# json schema semantics validation

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema

I have been given a [json](/questions/tagged/json) input which is a [jsonschema](/questions/tagged/jsonschema) and I need to validate that it is a valid [jsonschema](/questions/tagged/jsonschema) as in semantically.

I am using [newtonsoft](/questions/tagged/newtonsoft) and didn't find any api which validates the [jsonschema](/questions/tagged/jsonschema) itself to be a valid one. For instance if I want to validate a uri, I can use a constructor to make sure the input uri string is valid.

Is there a way to validate the semantics of [jsonschema](/questions/tagged/jsonschema)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the "meta schema".  [Found here](http://json-schema.org/documentation.html) under the Meta Schema heading.  They are specifically schema's for validating other schemas depending on what feature set you're using.